# R: append values of other rows to current row based on value of another column

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe (alter.hh2) like the following:

```
       wk         hh          brd     count       flavor mean_multi  h_size
    1  W52        1213        546        1          PEACH    2.11          2
    2  W52        4493        546        1          BBA      1.63          2
    5  W53        2093        5367       4          PEA      2.12          2
    6  W53        2043        5366       5          RBYA     1.93          1
    9  W53        2093        546        8          VANI     1.78          2
```

and for each row, I want to append the values of flavor (if different values), mean_multi, and brd, of the same week to it, like the following while keeping the remaining values untouched in each row:

```
 wk     hh     brd  count    flavor mean_multi  h_size flavor2 brd2 mean_multi2
 W52    1213   546   1      PEACH    2.11       2      BBA     546   1.63
 W52    4493   546   1      BBA      1.63       2      PEACH   546   2.11
 W53    2093   5367  4      PEA      2.12       2      RBYA    5367  1.93
 W53    2043   5366  5      RBYA     1.93       1      PEA     5366  2.12
```

if there are more than 2 values for each week, I want the result to be like the following (iteratively):

```
  wk    hh  brd  count flavor mean_multi h_size flavor2 brd2 mean_multi2 flavor3 brd3 mean_multi3
  W53   2093  5367  4     PEA    2.12       2   RBYA   5366  1.93          VANI   546  1.78   
  W53   2043  5366  5     RBYA   1.93       1   PEA    5367  2.12          VANI   546  1.78   
  W53   2093  546   8     VANI   1.78       2   PEA    5367  2.12          RBYA  5366  1.93
```

I have tried using the following code though reshape package, but it appears that it is not giving me the desired result:

```
 w <- reshape(alter.hh2, 
         timevar = c("flavor","wk"),
         idvar = c("count", "hh"),
         direction = "wide")
```

Would greatly any insights!

Comment: sorry. not giving me the desired result

Comment: count is just purchase count made by each hh.

Comment: I just want to make the second row values of "flavor", "mean_multi", and "brd" to some new column values of first row and do the same thing for the second row. And iterate this process for each week.

Comment: I posted a solution, please check.

Comment: If there are more than 2 values per wk, can you show the output

Comment: added what it will look if there are more than 2 values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Get the column names that we need to append (i.e. "brd",  "flavor", "mean_multi") if there are different values per "wk" ('nm1').  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(alter.hh2)`), grouped by 'hh', we select the first row (`head(.SD, 1)`), then grouped by 'wk' and specifying the `.SDcols`, we loop through the columns in `.SDcols` and get the reverse and assign (`:=`) the output to new columns.

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- names(alter.hh2)[c(3, 5, 6)]
setDT(alter.hh2)[,head(.SD, 1) , hh][, paste0(nm1, 2) := lapply(.SD, rev), 
           by = wk, .SDcols = nm1][]
#     hh  wk  brd count flavor mean_multi h_size brd2 flavor2 mean_multi2
#1: 1213 W52  546     1  PEACH       2.11      2  546     BBA        1.63
#2: 4493 W52  546     1    BBA       1.63      2  546   PEACH        2.11
#3: 2093 W53 5367     4    PEA       2.12      2 5367     PEA        2.12
#4: 2043 W53 5366     5   RBYA       1.93      1 5366    RBYA        1.93
```

Comment: I tried this on my own data, and it only goes to two values. I have 5 values for each row, so I am wondering how I should adjust the above code to accommodate this.

Comment: @lll Please update your post with a reproducible example as the second update have the count values 4, 5, and 8 while the 1 and 1 from the input example is not seen.